# Difference between tf.data.Dataset.repeat() vs iterator.initializer

Tags: python, tensorflow, repeat

Tensorflow has `tf.data.Dataset.repeat(x)` that iterates through the data `x` number of times. It also has `iterator.initializer` which when `iterator.get_next()` is exhausted, `iterator.initializer` can be used to restart the iteration. My question is is there difference when using `tf.data.Dataset.repeat(x)` technique vs `iterator.initializer`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As we know, each epoch in the training process of a model takes in the whole dataset and breaks it into batches. This happens on every epoch.
Suppose, we have a dataset with 100 samples. On every epoch, the 100 samples are broken into 5 batches ( of 20 each ) for feeding them to the model. But, if I have to train the model for say 5 epochs then, I need to **repeat** the dataset 5 times. Meaning, the total elements in the repeated dataset will have 500 samples ( 100 samples multipled 5 times ).

Now, this job is done by the `tf.data.Dataset.repeat()` method. Usually we pass the `num_epochs` argument to the method.

The `iterator.get_next()` is just a way of getting the next batch of data from the `tf.data.Dataset`. You are iterating the dataset batch by batch.

That's the difference. The `tf.data.Dataset.repeat()` repeats the samples in the dataset whereas `iterator.get_next()` one-by-one fetches the data in the form of batches.

Comment: @ Shubham Panchal , so is there need to initialize the iterator once you gone through the whole data if you are using repeat ?

Comment: Intializing the iterator once could help you iterate through the whole dataset ( repeated ).

Comment: Is repeat() just for performance optimization then?