# What is the use of repeat() when creating a tf.data.Dataset object?

Tags: python-3.x, repeat, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am reproducing the code of TensorFlow's [Time series forecasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#single_step_model) tutorial.

They use `tf.data` to shuffle, batch, and cache the dataset. More precisely they do the following:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 256
BUFFER_SIZE = 10000

train_univariate = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train_uni, y_train_uni))
train_univariate = train_univariate.cache().shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE).repeat()

val_univariate = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val_uni, y_val_uni))
val_univariate = val_univariate.batch(BATCH_SIZE).repeat()
```

I can't understand why they use `repeat()` and, even more so, why they don't specify the `count` argument of repeat. What is the point of making the process repeat indefinitely? And how can the algorithm read all the elements in an infinitely big dataset?

Comment: I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711103/difference-between-tf-data-dataset-repeat-vs-iterator-initializer) should help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between tf.data.Dataset.repeat() vs iterator.initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711103/difference-between-tf-data-dataset-repeat-vs-iterator-initializer)

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514495/what-does-batch-repeat-and-shuffle-do-with-tensorflow-dataset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As can be seen in the tutorials of [tensorflow federated for image classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification) the repeat method is used to use repetitions of the dataset that will also indicate *the number of epochs* for the training.

So use .repeat(NUM_EPOCHS) where NUM_EPOCHS is the number of epochs for the training.